# Try Analytics for Android

Tags: analytics

Am following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start).
I've installed the studio and google play services.

Try to achieve this step 1  : entering this command :
`$ git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git`

But I don't know where to enter it from the android studio.

https://www.screencast.com/t/YaVMxdwiH

Answer (score 0):

I 've moved 1 step forward! :)

I sum up how I manage to solve that out.

First of all, i had 1 error message: "can't run program:"git.exe etc..."

Solved by  this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faEd2syXypE

**Then** I launch the command for which I've been posting, here the steps :

https://www.screencast.com/t/qT589bXGjbkA

But now, I come across another issue witch is: **failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.0**
Look here: https://www.screencast.com/t/mCQQiV9HVrz8

Weird as I 've done all the update through sdk manager and followed this [help  page](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i manage again by playing with the version number, here :

https://www.screencast.com/t/tHVRDuqaAgDt

Now everything is fine, pay attention to set the global-tracker.xml file at the right place :

https://www.screencast.com/t/rELclq5x

Now i 've got 1 issue with simulating with my own device through usb connection , i've got this message : device offline, error installing APK

My device is developper enabled, i've installed apk already. Usb plugins are also all checked in android studio.

Look here for more details : https://www.screencast.com/t/V6BTHtQoB9V

Please help !!
Thanks